# Possible to get Flash Builder's mobile AIR simulator without Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, simulator

We are looking to make a mobile game that hits every platform. We want our remote graphic desingers to be able to easily see how their artwork looks in the game on lots of different devices. Is it there some program for this that you can stick an apk or ipa file into, and you can customize the simulated device to play it?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a windows AIR app and have it cycle through desired resolutions on some hotkey, that would probably be the simplest. Alternatively you can go with a solution like [Genymotion Android vitual machines](http://www.genymotion.com/), have them locally download a bunch of virtual machines and test it that way.

Mind you, that won't let the designers change the graphics on the fly and see how they look if that's what you had in mind, that would be a whole different situation. Also emulators won't let you gauge performance on different devices, they generally don't provide real world performance.